# Cannot download data from ArcGIS Online

Tags: arcgis-online, maps, download

I am new to ArcGIS Community, and I am currently following a MOOC to learn about ArcGIS.

When I try to add Data from ArcGIS Online on the ArcMap Desktop panel, some of this data simply never show up. 
It is the case for the "Terrain" map, looked for with the key word "elevation" : when I select it and click add, the map remains unchanged, so do my layers.

I tried to reboot the normal.mxt feature as suggested by someone on a similar case, but it has had little effect so far.

My version is ArcGIS Desktop 10.7.11595

Comment: Terrain Datasets require a 3D Analyst license... http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/terrains/what-is-a-terrain-dataset-.htm